# Why is my android device rebooting after connected to bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Samsung Galaxy M11 wich after i connect it to bluetooth and trying to play audio on PC immediatelly restarts.This happens after i've made some software updates.First i updated the soft while being on Android 10,before this update it wasn't rebooting,and then i updated to Android 11 thinking it might fix the problem but it didn't.
Any ideas?

Comment: May be something went wrong upgrading the pairing between both devices. Have you tried to unpaid them and then reestablish the Bluetooth pairing? If that does not help the manufacturer may have introduced a bug with one of the updates. You can enable Android Debug Bridge and check `adb logcat` right before the device reboots. May be you see an error message that helps you to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: I've unpair them and right in the moment i tried to pair them the device rebooted.

Comment: Do i have to enable Usb debugging to use adb logcat?Because i don't want to.

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't reboots anymore.I enabled the USB debugging and connected the phone via USB to PC and used adb logcat and it doesn't restarts anymore.I also cleared the cache partition.

Comment: It happened again...:(

Comment: Having USB debugging and adb enabled is in my opinion recommended on modern devices because this allows you in case you screen is damaged to still get access to large parts of your data on the phone so you can create a backup and move to new phone if you don't repair the old phone. As USB debugging is limited to those PCs you have authorized to access your phone there to my knowledge nothing negative in having adb enabled.

Comment: Yes,i know that it is better with USB debugging enabled,i already did that but i didn't wanted to do it because this phone i bought it on wednesday so..it was a new phone,idk.How can i post the logcat here?Because it is an ending log,i mean after i write adb -s "device id" logcat in terminal it starts an ending writing,i mean it's too long.

Comment: [This](https://products.groupdocs.app/editor/wysiwyg/WordProcessing/3364342c-89d3-40ca-aacd-ef8373a49596/logcat.txt) is the logcat when the device restarted:

Comment: The phone doesn't reboots anymore after a factory reset.